# Importing a sql dump to Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse

I have imported a dumped sql file from MySQl Workbench, but when I try to run in Eclipse I keep getting this error message.

SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COL' at line 8

But when I copy the same information into MySQL it creates the schema and everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my java code:
http://pastebin.com/B1RVMYUd

And if you need it here is the dumpfile:
http://pastebin.com/RWpG0BEX

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe better to upload dump in query in your mysql statement

Answer (score 0):

You execute the whole contents of the dump as a single SQL statement. Try splitting the file contents (your `sql` String) using `;` as the delimiter, and execute each statement separately.

(As an aside, it's good practice to put the calls to `statement.close`/`conn.close` in a `finally` clause, to make sure that the resources are always released.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner, so my comments may not be the most clear or accurate, nor my code the most clear, concise, correct, etc.  With that out of the way, here are a few things:

1) You can't use executeQuery(sql) method to create.  So use one of the other options.  In my experiments, I used:

```
sqlDumpArray = sqlDump.split(";");

for (int i = 0; i < sqlDumpArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("\nsqlDumpArray[" + i + "] is: " + sqlDumpArray[i]); // To see what's in the array.
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < sqlDumpArray.length -1; j++) { // Ugly hack because sqlDumpArray[0] and sqlDumpArray.length-1 are problematic in this alpha version of code.
       try {
          Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
          statement.addBatch(sqlDumpArray[j]);               
          statement.executeBatch(); // Maybe could move this out of the for-loop.
       }
```

Regarding the SQL file:

1) Strip out the comments.
2) Put a semicolon as the first character of the file (i.e., row 1, column 1).

I did that and it works.  Let me know if you want my complete code and I'll post it.

Cheers,
Chris